# How to permanently stop alertmanager-operated service from using port 9093 on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, port, prometheus-alertmanager

I installed Prometheus chart kube-prometheus-stack-19.2.3 on my cluster. There is an issue with the service alertmanager-operated as it uses port 9093 as one of its web ports. This is the same port as another one of my applications and so it prevents that deployment from starting up.

I can edit the service to use another port and it works fine but there is something triggering it to randomly switch back to using port 9093 which is causing my application to crash. I can't seem to figure out what causes it to revert - sometimes it can go a few days and other times it switches back after a minute or so. Any way to permanently change the port?

Comment: How did you change alertmanager port? With values.yaml before deploying, or with kubectl on already deployed resource?

Comment: with kubectl edit svc alertmanager-operated.  i am not hosting the helm in my own repo you see, I just got it from the internet source.

Comment: What do you mean your application can't start if it's using the same port? `alertmanager-operated` is of type ClusterIP, yo ucan have multpiple ClusterIP services using the same port. Also, how exactly did you install prometheus stack? Did you specifiy any commands?

Comment: Should you use a different hostname for alertmanager exposed service?

Prometheus operator is the one recreating it with default settings. You can check it out here: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/rbac.md.